# Dualizing Sheaf of $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}^{3}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi :\widetilde{\mathbb{P}^{3}} \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{3}$ be the blowup of $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ along a regular curve $\mathcal{C}$, with exceptional divisor $E$. We know the following: If $X$ is a projective nonsingular variety over an algebraically closed field $\mathcal{K}$, then dualizing sheaf $\omega^{\circ}_{X}$ is isomorphic to the canonical sheaf $\omega_{X}$.

What's the dualizing sheaf of $\widetilde{\mathbb{P}^3}$?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for? As you've said, on this variety the dualizing sheaf is isomorphic to the canonical sheaf - what information do you want in addition to this or instead of this statement?

Comment: What's the dualizing sheaf of $\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}^{3}$? What is the contribution of exceptional divisor?

Comment: $\omega_{\mathbb{P}^{3}} = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(-4)$. Then, $\omega_{\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}^{3}} = $??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical sheaf of a blowup $f:Y\to X$ satisfies the relation $K_Y = f^*(K_X) + (c-1)E$ where $c$ is the codimension of what you're blowing up and $E$ is the exceptional divisor (see Griffiths and Harris page 187 for a proof, for example - the case where there's a nontrivial meromorphic top form is easy and you may wish to try that yourself). Since the canonical and dualizing sheaves coincide here, you have your answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, KReiser !!